Azure Data Factory - mapping data flow with pagination
I am using REST Api as a source for the incoming data and the URL is in this form
https://<baseUrl>/endPoint?per_page=50&page=<Page##>

The response comes without any mention of the next url, but with the following in the body
...
"meta":{
    "count": 50,
    "total_count": 2003
}
...

So that suggest that I am having a 41 total number of pages.
In the ADF Copy activity I got pagination working perfectly with using Range option in pagination rules section and the EndCondition.

But the problem is that because of the complex nested data in the response, Copy activity does not suit the needs.  The mapping data flow has to be used to sync to Cache output. (I have stored procedure to take care of it on the target side).
But, I do not know how to implement pagination, since there is no End Condition....
Please, suggest any advise ...

Under COPY Activity -> Mapping  did you checked the "Map complex values to string" it usually store all the nested value as string and once you stored it to staging table you can add transformation logic to clean it..

Range is not supported in Mapping Dataflow also the End condition is different from Copy Activity. Please see the Note section under Pagination for more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#pagination-support


I do not know how to implement pagination, since there is no End Condition.... Please, suggest any advise.

In Mapping data flow Range pagination is not supported for Rest API.
To achieve your requirement, you can try two workarounds as below:

Using For-each activity and dataflow under it
-- For this using web activity first get the response and, you need to calculate the total no of pages using output of web activity as below using set variable.

-- You can use range function to iterate over range using @range(1,variables('total no of pages')) function.

--  Under This For each take dataflow with parameterized dataset as follow: In your source dataset create  pageparam  parameter  in dataset Add your relative URL like below:

@concat('endPoint?per_page=50&page=',string(dataset().pageparam))

Then in dataflow source parameters add for each iterator to source parameter.  
Then you can further process the data.

Using Copy activity and dataflow.
-- First copy nested Json using copy activity from paginated Rest Api to blob storage.
-- Then transform the nested Json using Data flow into required format.


Thanks for the reply.
Using For loop I can do it with the regular Rest reques, I won't need a mapping data flow.
Unfortunately, the for loop takes too long.  I wanted to use the dataflow, thinking it can be faster running, and give me the full json response.  Otherwise, for loop with the Web activity gives me what I want
